# Highly persistent exchange rate within a bound: alternatives to integration and stationarity tests

Tags: stationarity, random-walk

I was trying to assess stability using a stationarity test. If an exchange rate is fix, I thought, it must be stationary around its parity.

Unfortunately I realised this approach does not work.

Hong Kong has a fixed parity with the dollar, 7.8 HKD per USD. However, the monetary authority intervenes only if the exchange rate is below 7.75 or above 7.85. Hong Kong has an (extremely narrow) band.

Now, within this band the exchange rate is very persistent, as you can see from the picture.

[[image: HK exchange rate]

ADF rejects the hypothesis of stationarity, and I can imagine why: the series does not revert to the centre, it just do not go below or above a certain bound.
However, it seems to me clear that it is not a random walk: if it were, when the exchange rate is at 7.75 mark there would be an equal probability of falling below and of rising above this mark, while clearly there is not.
I wonder if there is a test that formalises this kind of problems.
A possibility coming to my mind is to consider the probability distribution of the shock, in this case we have a shock, which is dependent on the value of the series, if the series is at 7.75 the shock can only be 0 or positive, never negative. The opposite is the case if the series is at 7.85.

Any suggestion?

Comment: How do you define stability? Perhaps the definition can inspire some tests, as we need to know what qualifies a counterexample and what does not.

Comment: Stable is a series, which remains within a range. The narrower the range, the stabler is the series.

A random walk y requires that the expected value of the innovation is zero and its probability distribution symmetric, i.e. the probability of an increase or of a decrease are the same. Here it is not the case: if the series hits the floor or the ceiling, the probability of going beyond is equal to zero. Therefore, it cannot be a pure random walk.